# stuck halfway between npm and bower

Tags: bower, browserify

I started an Ampersand.js+Browserify+Gulp.js project using a Yeoman generator.  It created both an NPM-managed package.json and a Bower-managed bower.json.

This is weird to me because people cloning the project have to install packages from both those systems when setting up the project:

```
npm install
bower install
```

I want to keep Browserify and Gulp.js.  What's the best way to move the Bower stuff out of Bower?

For reference, here's my bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.1.1",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": ">=3.3.0",
    "modernizr": "^2.8.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What's the best way to move the Bower stuff out of Bower

You don't need to!

[**jquery**](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jquery), [**bootstrap-sass**](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bootstrap-sass), and [**modernizr**](https://www.npmjs.org/package/modernizr) are already in npm registry. Just do:

```
npm install jquery bootsrap-sass modernizr --save
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying your suggestion.  The gulp ruby sass task isn't able to find my main.scss's @import "bootstrap-sass";  What should my loadPath be?  I've tried 'node_modules', 'node_modules/boostrap_sass', 'node_modules/boostrap_sass/assets', and 'node_modules/bootstrap_sass/assets/stylesheets'

Comment: Try **node_modules/bootstrap-sass/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.scss**